# Colour map axes tick labels in python

Tags: python, axis, axis-labels, colormap

I've written a code that creates a colour map. It plots values that correspond to many pixels that start at 60, 60 and the last pixel is 70, 70. Unfortunately the tick labels on the axis default to a relative scale rather than the absolute value of the pixels, here is a picture of the plot that is produced: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvsEk.png What I would like is for the axis to say 60, 61, 62 etc.

The code I'm using to get the plot is:
            plt.imshow(z, cmap='gnuplot_r')
            plt.colorbar

Any help would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is a keyword argument for `imshow` that can be used for setting the 
min and max values of the x and y axis of the image.

```
imshow(X, cmap=None, norm=None, aspect=None, interpolation=None,
       alpha=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, origin=None, extent=None,
       **kwargs)
```

The argument can be given as a tuple (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax).